# jquery autoplay function works only once

Tags: javascript, jquery

I copyed this code from this page http://jquery.lemmonjuice.com/plugins/slider-variable-widths.php but on my page the autoplay function works only once.
Can you help me?

```
var sliderTimeout;
window.onload = function(){
// initialize slider
$( '#slider1' ).lemmonSlider({

    'slideToLast' : true

});
// run
sliderAutoplay();
}
// slider autoplay function
function sliderAutoplay(){

$( '#slider1' ).trigger( 'nextSlide' );
sliderTimeout = setTimeout( 'sliderAutoplay', 3000 );

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove the single quotes for the setTimeout function function the first argument be function not a string.

```
sliderTimeout = setTimeout(sliderAutoplay, 3000 );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
setInterval(function(){ sliderAutoplay() },3000);
```

Try this